# Pyspark Structured Streaming application print execution time per file in console

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to measure execution time and profile a Pyspark structured streaming from the application itself. For example, I want to execute a Python script with basically

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
import time   

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sc = SparkSession.builder.master('spark://localhost:7077').getOrCreate()
    df = sc.readStream.schema(pq_schema).parquet('../data/parquet')
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_table")
    exec_query = sc.sql("""
            select sum(field_1), count(field_2), field_3 from vw_table group by field_3
    """)
    result_q = df_st.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()
    result_q.awaitTermination()
```

Then I would copy a file to the folder and check each file time. Is it possible to do it from the Python script?

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose, you can reduce number of files per trigger:

```py
df = sc.readStream.schema(pq_schema)\
     .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)\
     .parquet('../data/parquet')
```

Then you find each batch duration in Spark UI.
Or you can add a timestamp in each bath(for a test in local). this code is not recommended and It does not always work properly.it's a quick hack.

```py
from datetime import datetime

startTime= datetime.now()
batchId = 1

def batch_duration(df, epoch_id):
        global startTime,batchId
        print("proccess time for batch {} = {}".format(batchId,datetime.now() - startTime))
        startTime= datetime.now()
        batchId+=1

result_q = df_st.writeStream\
                      .outputMode("complete")\
                      .foreachBatch(batch_duration)\
                      .start()\
                      .awaitTermination()
```